# Is there a way to center code text in Netbeans to the screen?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm trying to emulate my prior darkroom setup I've had with emacs, but with Netbeans. I'm pretty much all the time in alt-shift-enter full screen mode, and then shift-escape to maximize the code editor screen. However, this results in all of the code text editor block, along with line numbers, to be aligned to the left of the screen. Is it possible, even via third party plugins, to center all of the block to the center of the screen?

version of netbeans is 6.7m3

Comment: You are running bleeding edje. Why use a milestone when 6.5 is stable?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, try reporting it to netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time, but there still doesn't seem to be a dedicated way to do that (in NB 11.2 in my case). Here's a workaround that works for me:

Create or open an empty file and drag the file's editor container away from the other open file tabs to the left side of the window so you have two documents side by side. Now drag the separator between them to the left to center the code of the right document. Voilà.

Works great in fullscreen mode (Alt + Shift + Enter), but doesn't work in editor-only mode (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) which will only show one editor.